# Some inequalities involving binomial coefficients in Erdös' Graph Theory and Probability

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a (sufficiently large) positive integer, and $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Let $0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{k}$ and $0 < \eta < \epsilon / 2$ be arbitrary. Define $m = \lfloor n^{1 + \epsilon} \rfloor$ and $p = \lfloor n^{1 - \eta} \rfloor$.

I am working on the result from Erdös' [Graph Theory and Probability](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/graph-theory-and-probability/154EF813293BC7D0652C4CBCD9D18E84) that for any $k$ and $r$ there exists a graph with no cycles of length $\leq k$ and chromatic number $> r$ using the probabilistic method. It seems many modern treatments are more explicitly probabilistic, but I would like to understand a bit more of the classic techniques used.

In particular, I would like some help in understanding the following two inequalities from (p35), which I cannot get:
$$
(n + 1) \binom{\binom{p}{2}}{n} \binom{\binom{n}{2} - \binom{p}{2}}{m} < p^{2n} \binom{\binom{n}{2} - \binom{m}{2}}{m} < \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m} p^{2n} \left( 1 - \frac{\binom{p}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}} \right)^{m} .
$$

If anyone might be able to share some hints or tricks for dealing with these binomial coefficients, that would be really helpful.

---

Attempt:

- A basic inequality that I believe might be useful is $\frac{n^k}{k^k} \leq \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}$. This seems to get some promising results, but I can't seem to pushit through to get the whole desired result, so I am probably missing some key steps.
- For the first inequality, $\binom{p}{2} \leq \frac{p^2}{2}$, so we have $\binom{\binom{p}{2}}{n} \leq \frac{p^{2n}}{2^n n!} \leq p^{2n}$. So this gives one part of it. But I am unsure how the $(n+1)$ (and perhaps the $\frac{1}{2^n n!}$ part) can be used to change the upper index of the binomial coefficient. Note that $\binom{n}{2} - \binom{p}{2} > \binom{n}{2} - \binom{m}{2}$.
- For the second inequality, I have tried to use $\binom{\binom{n}{2} - \binom{m}{2}}{m} \leq \frac{\left[\binom{n}{2} - \binom{m}{2}\right]^m}{m!} \leq \frac{\left[\binom{n}{2} - \binom{p}{2}\right]^m}{m!}$. If I use the $1/m!$ term to create the first binomial coefficient, I can write $\frac{1}{m!} = \frac{\binom{n}{2}!}{m! \left(\binom{n}{2} - m\right)!} \frac{\left(\binom{n}{2} - m\right)!}{\binom{n}{2}!} = \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m} \frac{\left(\binom{n}{2} - m\right)!}{\binom{n}{2}!}$. So far so good, but then I can only get $\frac{\left(\binom{n}{2} - m\right)!}{\binom{n}{2}!} \leq \frac{1}{\left[\binom{n}{2} - m\right]^m}$, whereas I want the upper bound to be $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}^m}$.